# Determine how Mathematica was started

Tags: kernel, command-line

I have a notebook that I also execute as a m file on the command line.
Depending on whether I run the notebook or the m file, I want to use slightly different commands.
For example, `NotebookDirectory[]` in the nb file should be replaced by `Directory[]` in the m file.
Is there a way to read out how Mathematica was started (on the command line or as a notebook) so that I can use the same file to handle the two different situations?

Other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is more complicated that you might expect.

Things you can check:

- Given how you want to use this, the simplest thing may be to just check if `NotebookDirectory[]` is different from `$Failed`.
- The documentation would suggest [`$Notebooks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Notebooks.html), but be careful: this is `True` even if running in command line mode but connecting to a front end anyway, e.g. `UsingFrontEnd[$Notebooks]` will be `True`.  For practical purposes it may work well.
- There is `$ParentLink`.  It is set to something else than `Null` when the kernel is being used through a MathLink connection, which includes the cases when there is a front end present, but may also include other scenarios when the kernel is used through MathLink.  I checked that with `MathematicaScript`, `$ParentLink` is still `Null` (even though AFAIK `MathematicaScript` uses MathLink to invoke the kernel (??)).
- There is `$ScriptCommandLine`, which will be non-empty when using `MathematicaScript` (but not when invoking the kernel from the command line in other ways).
- There is `$BatchInput` (look it up).
- `$InputFileName` will be set when reading an `.m` file using `Get`.  This may be the most robust solution.

Comment: To check that `$ParentLink` is the usual FE, one can use `MathLink\`NotebookFrontEndLinkQ[$ParentLink]`